# I am getting an error in my java program as : constructor Try1 in class Try1 cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

I am trying to implement constructor overloading in java. I think everything is perfect but it shows this error:

> Main.java:28: error: constructor Tryme in class Tryme cannot be
>   applied to given types;
>
> ```
>    Tryme s=new Tryme(1,1,2015);
>            ^   required: no arguments   found: int,int,int   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error .
> ```

Here is my code:

```
      import java.util.*;

      class Try1 {
        int day,month,year;``
        public void Try1() {
          day = 1;
          month = 1;
          year = 2015;
        }

        public void Try1(int d,int m,int y) {
          day = d;
          month = m;
          year = y;
        }

        public void seter() {
          System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
        }
      }

      class MDate {
        public static void main(String []str) {
          Try1 t = new Try1();
          t.seter();
          Try1 s=new Try1(1,1,2015);
          s.seter();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Constructors are not `void`

Comment: Did you define the constructor in class `Tryme`?

Answer (score 1):

Constructor does not used any explicit return type but you used void as return type. You have to remove void from the constructor.

Use constructor like below :

```
       public Try1() {
           day = 1;
           month = 1;
           year = 2015;
       }

       public Try1(int d, int m, int y) {
           day = d;
           month = m;
           year = y;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **constructor syntax is different from any other method**.

A normal method has a return type, **a constructor has not a return type**.

So the correct syntax for your constructor are (please not the absence of return type, *also `void` is a return type*)

```
public Try1() {
    day = 1;
    month = 1;
    year = 2015;
}
```

and

```
public Try1(int d,int m,int y) {
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}
```